# How to find ids on array who is created facet operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, aggregate, mongoid

I have Customer collection on MongoDB. With status field. Which can have the same Id fields.
And I need find first changed value like 'Guest' and push it Id's to specific pipeline named as 'guests'.
And customers with status 'Member' I need push tu another pipeline named as 'members' who Id'd equal Id's from aggregation pipeline 'guests'.
This is done in order to obtain the quantity elements in 'guests' and 'members'.

Its member item:

```
{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"5ce2ecb3ad71852e7fa9e73f"},
       "status"=>"member",
       "duration"=>nil,
       "is_deleted"=>false,
       "customer_id"=>"17601",
       "customer_journal_item_id"=>"62769",
       "customer_ids"=>"17601",
       "customer_journal_item_ids"=>"62769",
       "self_customer_status_id"=>"21078",
       "self_customer_status_created_at"=>"2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
       "self_customer_status_updated_at"=>"2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
       "updated_at"=>"2019-05-20T18:06:43.655Z",
       "created_at"=>"2019-05-20T18:06:43.655Z"}}
```

My aggregation

```
    {
        '$sort': {'self_customer_status_created_at': 1}
    }, 
    {'$match': 
        {
            'self_customer_status_created_at': 
            {
                "$gte": Time.parse('2017-01-17').beginning_of_month, 
                "$lte": Time.parse('2017-01-17').end_of_month 
            }
        } 
    }, 
    {
        "$facet": {
            "guests": 
            [ 
                { 
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$_id", 
                        "data": {
                            '$first': '$$ROOT'
                        } 
                    } 
                }, 
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "data.status": "guest"
                    }
                }, {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id":nil, 
                        "array":{
                            "$push": "$data.self_customer_status_id" 
                        } 
                    } 
                }, 
                { 
                    "$project":{
                        "array": 1,
                        "_id":0
                    } 
                }
            ], "members": 
            [ 
                { 
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$_id", "data": {
                            '$last': '$$ROOT'
                        } 
                    } 
                }, 
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "data.status": "member",
                        "data.self_customer_status_id": {
                            "$in": [
                                    "$guests.array"
                                  ]
                            }  
                        } 
                    }
                } 
            ] 
        } 
    }, {
        "$project": 
        { 
            "members": 1, 
            "guests.array": 1 
        } 
        } 
    ]
).as_json
```

Instead "guests.array" array? I have error:

`Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: $in needs an array (2)`

What am I doing wrong?
Sorry my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

second expression in faced doesnt seen first expression
need delete

```
,
                        "data.self_customer_status_id": {
                            "$in": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": 
                                [
                                    "$guests.array", 
                                    0
                                ]
                            }  
                        }
```

````
    {"$match": {"data.self_customer_status_id": { "$in": ["guests.array"] } } }
    ```
this link paste before $project
````